# Order by and group by not working in php codeigniter?

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

table format :
table name category:

```
      id       title
   -----------------
      1          xyz
      2          abc
```

table name subcategory:

```
     id        category_id    start_date      status
 ----------------------------------------------------------
     1             1            2016-11-03       1
     2             1            2016-11-09       1
     3             2            2016-10-03       1
     4             3            2016-12-03       1
     5             3            2016-12-05       1
     6             5            2016-12-06       1
```

query:

```
      $date = date('Y-m-d');
      $this->db->select('*');
      $this->db->where('status',1);
      $this->db->where('start_date >=',$date);
      $this->db->order_by('start_date', 'asc');
      $this->db->group_by('category_id');
      $this->db->limit(4);
      $query = $this->db->get('subcategory');
      return $query->result();
```

my problem is: i want result as subcategory_id 1,4,6 . but group_by and order by is not working.

**Error:**

> SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated
>   column 'dbname.subcategory.id' which is not functionally dependent on
>   columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with
>   sql_mode=only_full_group_by SELECT * FROM (subcategory) WHERE status =
>   1 AND start_date >= '2016-11-03' GROUP BY category_id ORDER BY
>   start_date asc LIMIT 4

Comment: what is the error message??

Comment: SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'dbname.subcategory.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

SELECT * FROM (`subcategory`) WHERE `status` = 1 AND `start_date` >= '2016-11-03' GROUP BY `category_id` ORDER BY `start_date` asc LIMIT 4

Comment: is your mysql version 7?

Comment: add this line at the end of your `my.cnf` file
`sql_mode = "STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"` . Then restart mysql.

Answer (score 0):

**change your query:**
first there should be group by then order by

```
$date = date('Y-m-d');
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->where('status',1);
$this->db->where('start_date >=',$date);
$this->db->group_by('category_id');
$this->db->order_by('start_date', 'asc');
$this->db->limit(4);
$query = $this->db->get('subcategory');
return $query->result();
```

Or print a query by doing this after `$query` and check for the same in database:

```
echo $this->db->last_query();
```

Comment: I think it does not matter where you place the group_by when you are using ActiveRecord. You can verify it by printing the query.

Comment: @SayantanDas let him try.

Comment: i try your code but it's give same error SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'dbname.subcategory.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by SELECT * FROM (subcategory) WHERE status = 1 AND start_date >= '2016-11-03' GROUP BY category_id ORDER BY start_date asc LIMIT 4

Comment: @K.doe that means you have to use one aggregated function when you use **group by** clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = date('Y-m-d');
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->group_by('category_id');
$this->db->limit(4);
$query = $this->db->get("(SELECT * FROM subcategory where status=1 and start_date>='$date' order by start_date) as subcategory");
return $query->result();
```

Comment: the user wants all data not only comma separated ids. also, add some information what should be changed.

Comment: can you please explain?